# How can I fix my endpoint not accepting POST requests?

Tags: javascript, typescript, api, express

I'm building a custom API, with an endpoint defined as follow:

[image: API Endpoint Spec]

I have a created a `Profiling` Controller to handle the logic for this endpoint. My controller directory contains 2 files:

1. `controller.ts`

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import ProfilingService from '../../services/profiling.service';

export class Controller {
  enrich_profile(req: Request, res: Response): void {
    console.log(req);
    ProfilingService.enrich_profile(req).then((r) =>
      res
        .status(201)
        .location(`/api/v1/profile_data/enrich_profile/data${r}`)
        .json(r)
    );
  }
}
export default new Controller();
```

2. `routes.ts`

```
/* eslint-disable prettier/prettier */
import express from 'express';
import controller from './controller';
export default express.
    Router()
    .post('/enrich_profile', controller.enrich_profile)
;
```

However, when I sent a call to the endpoint, I get the following error:

[image: API Endpoint Error Message]

And finally, to allow a full picture, here's the content of `profiling.service.ts`:

```
import L from '../../common/logger';

interface Profiling {
  data: never;
}

export class ProfilingService {
  enrich_profile(data: never): Promise<Profiling> {
    console.log(data);
    L.info(`update user profile using \'${data}\'`);
    const profile_data: Profiling = {
      data,
    };
    return Promise.resolve(profile_data);
  }
}

export default new ProfilingService();
```

The error clearly states that `POST` to the defined endpoint is not possible, and I'm not sure I understand why.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem. The snippets work for me.

Comment: That's tough.

I have another controller dealing with another endpoint that works just fine. Maybe that's the problem? I didn't mention it because I didn't think it was relevant, but maybe it is?

Comment: I don't know but your problem is not reproducible. You could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not sure what was causing the issue, but after cleaning my npm cache, and deleting node_modules about 100X, the issue finally went away.